# how to Insert multiple rows from array saved in a session into table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm passing multiple state values that are stored in a session variable, into a MySQL table via php using one insert command and I'm wondering if its possible to insert each state value into a different row. I also have an ID saved in a variable that I would like to insert with each state.

$campaign_id
Each state is stored in this session variable.

print_r($_SESSION['stateslist']);
Assuming I have two states saved in the $_SESSION['stateslist'] (NY, CA) and campaign ID 5, I would like my database to look like this

```
campaign_id    state
   5             NY
   5             CA
```

I know it is something similar to this insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql but I am having problems inserting each state saved in the session as well as the campaign_id.

Comment: Kindly do not post the same question several times it will not help you nor will help us.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to pass along some variables from one script to another, but if you really want to use session vars for that, I guess you should:

cast your key-value array as an associative array

```
$myvar=array('campaign_id'=>5, 'states'=>array('NY,CA'));
```

json_encode it into a string which will fit into your session variable.

```
  $_SESSION['campaign_state']=json_encode($myvar);
```

once you retrieve the session var you json_decode it:

```
 $myarray=json_decode($_SESSION['campaign_state'],true);
```

iterate over the 'states' key:

```
$query=array();
foreach($myarray['states'] as $state) {
    $query[]=insert into mytable (campaign,state) values ({$myarray['campaign_id')},$state);
}
```

It's a dirty cheap solution and you still should sanitize those variables.

Comment: thanks, I am going to give it a try. I am only using session variables because I had to use header( "Location: "" );   in my forms and I did not want to pass the information through my URL.